# Can't see any content on wiki.rubyonrails.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wiki

Am I the only one who doesn't see any content when visiting [wiki.rubyonrails.org](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/)?

[Screen Shot](http://static.inky.ws/image/779/image.jpg)

Comment: Is Stack Overflow really the right place to ask this?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: I think Programmers.SE would be a better spot for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails wiki has been broken for quite a long time. I would really recommend just ignoring it. It was never maintained as a "core" part of the Rails ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I viewed the page you linked with several browsers (IE8, FF5, Opera 11, Safari) and each time it looked the same as the screen shot you provided.